# How i can ensure user that my program do not read data from hdd?

Tags: windows, security

I make program for windows, that work with internet and self local dababase. How i can ensure user, which install program, that my program do not send his data and document thru internet to me. I think do this my limit premissions to program, but windowsXP for exemple, do not have this feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach here is to publish the source code and sign the binary. That way, really suspicious users can compile the program themselves (after making sure their compiler hasn't been tampered with) while more trusting souls can use you signed version.

Note that you this doesn't mean you have to give the sources to everyone. Just provide a way to contact you in case they want the source.

Alternatively, you can send the sources to an expert and have them certify that your program doesn't do anything evil. They can then sign the binary as well.